# What does the regex (?:\s|^)@ do?

Tags: javascript, regex

I think that it means "match a space at the start of the word, but don't capture it".

How do I modify this to include periods?

I've tried

```
(?:[\s.]|^)@
```

?

Comment: It matches `@` at the beginning of a string or preceded by a space. Your change looks OK.

Comment: @FelixKling or preceded by any number of these `\t \r \n \b` etc..

Comment: @aduch: Yeah, I meant "whitespace" ;)

Comment: ah, so how do I modify it so that it matches @ at the beginning of a string Or a dot? I've also tried (?:\s|^|?:\.)

Comment: Your expression works totally fine: `/(?:[\s.]|^)@/.test('foo.@bar')`. If it doesn't for you, then you have to provide more information about  your input and desired output.

Comment: so  I guess it's not working on Start of sentence.@mention.Another sentence. But this is another issue - I'll post up another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches an `@` that is preceded by either the start of the string or a space. Your change would work: it would capture an `@` that is preceded by one of the following (1) the start of the string, (2) a space, or (3) a period.

Here's a graphical explanation:

```
(?:[\s.]|^)@
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/T_FvEMTmwE800nVx)

Comment: so how do I modify it to match the dot?

Comment: @praks5432 Sorry, submitted answer too quickly. Please see my edit.